# Conceptual model vs normalization. ER diagrams EER diagrams

Tags: database, normalization, conceptual, eer-model

I have a question about those four thing because they confuse me. Whats the difference between conceptual model and normalization ? Also where ER and EER are belongs to Conceptual model or normalization?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Conceptual models are informal.  Examples of conceptual models are ER diagrams and (when explicitly used for the purpose of conceptual modeling) UML class diagrams.

Normalization is a procedure that can be applied to *formal* models consisting of :

(a) all the relation schemas involved in the design
(b) all the functional dependencies applying to the individual relation schemas

Normalization, and assessing normal form of a given design, can only be applied to *formal* models, and does not apply to informal/conceptual models and/or modeling techniques such as (E)ER.